# How to deploy flutter web app on isp manager

Tags: flutter, hosting, flutter-web

I am new to flutter web hosting and the client gave me isp manager server to host the app on it.

I have searched a lot but with no good result.

Plus on that. I have never host any website before because I'm mobile developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:** Build your Flutter Web App with the following command:

```
flutter build web
```

You will find the result of the build inside the folder `build/web` with contents similar to the following:

```
├───assets
│   ├───assets
│   │   ├───images
│   │   └───translations
│   ├───fonts
│   └───packages
│       ├───cupertino_icons
│       │   └───assets
│       └───easy_localization
│           └───i18n
├───canvaskit
│   └───profiling
└───icons
```

**Second:** Use this official [video guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oQT21mzkDdo) from ISPsystem to learn how to host the web app.

Note that the files you will uploading for the web app will be all content of `build/web` folder.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I did what it say in the video but when I call the domain name nothing show.

Comment: Is there any configs i have to do in my index.html file?

Comment: No configs required, I want you to test the connection of the host with domain by just adding a file named `index.html` with just any dummy text inside and put the files of your Flutter app in a temporary folder so the new `index.html` become in the root of your host folder, then access the domain and see if you find the dummy text you wrote appears or not.

Comment: You're always welcome ❤